# How to speed up web development with correct Apache caching headers setup?

Tags: apache, caching, header, apache2

Despite various measure ments to setup correct caching code in htaccess file, I still get this error:

> *Specify a cache validator*: 
>   All static resources should have either a Last-Modified or ETag header. This will allow browsers to take advantage of the full benefits of caching.

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my htaccess caching settings? If you have improvements for these settings i will be very happy to hear. Thank you very much for your suggestions.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Pragma
  FileETag None
  Header unset ETag
  ExpiresActive On

  ##### DYNAMIC PAGES
  <FilesMatch "\\.(ast|php|css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600, must-revalidate"
  </FilesMatch>

  ##### STATIC FILES
  <FilesMatch "\\.(png|svg|swf|js|xml)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=604800, must-revalidate"
    Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>

##### ETERNAL FILES
<FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpg|gif|ttf|eot|pdf|flv)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=7257600, must-revalidate"
    Header unset Last-Modified
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: As soon as I saw the image I knew this was a question from you :P

Comment: Thats very flattering mate :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifically unsetting the Last-Modified header.  That's the cache validator section.  Remove those lines that include:

```
Header unset Last-Modified
```

Also, is your css really dynamic?  CSS can be huge for a lot of websites.  Try to cache that just like any other static content.

Comment: Thanks very much @SquawKnull or @SquAwknull or @skuawkNULL! that did the trick. I must have copy pastet that without knowing what it does. Does that line say something like: `"whatever was set on header Last-Modified, erase it"` ?

Comment: Essentially, yes.  It will remove that header entirely.

Answer (score 1):

All static resources should have either a Last-Modified or ETag header. This will allow browsers to take advantage of the full benefits of caching.