# How to speed up a website's HEADERS load time?

Tags: performance, header, http-headers, pagespeed, yslow

After thorough optimizations of my website (scoring 95 on google PageSpeed & 96 Yahoo YSLOW) I am puzzled by why the header(s?) take up a *relatively* long time to load. Is 11 KBytes header information not normal? How should a website in which its slowness is caused by headers, be optimized? Suggestions, tests and tricks for php/htaccess are greatly appreciated in order to find and isolate this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you tell us more about your environment. which server, you are using apache httpd, right? which version, what else are you using, tomcat? something else, etc...

Comment: Dear Moataz: Apache/2.0.54 (Fedora) shared hosting with plesk controls, PHP 5.17 I believe so thats all up to date

Comment: its not a direct answer, but are you aware of these tips from yahoo? http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: basically the most important things to take care of is to add caching, cache control and longer expiry dates, this has unfortunately no direct influence on the header request, but who knows

Comment: there's also this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480773/how-to-speed-up-web-development-with-correct-apache-caching-headers-setup

Comment: the domain is by the way CDN (Content Delivery Network) enabled and all caches are far future caches!

Comment: are you sure they are far future caches? only because its CDN doesnt mean necessarily its caches are optimized

Comment: Yep, sure! set in many rules in the htaccess that define the duration of caches in milliseconds and all elements are cached properly, so its not the length of duration of the caches... Anyhow, interesting to hear that headers has mainly something to do with caching of files(reading from your answer) I did not know that!

Comment: ok, so lets assume for a second that its not apache problem. and examine php. are you using pure php, maybe javascrit, which library?etc.. are you manipulating the headers?

Comment: just to make sure its a problem with your website not with the php engine. install a php framework, for example mediawiki and see if it has the same lagging, if yes then its a php optimization problem/or php module under apache problem. if not, then with high probability its your code/website problem

Comment: No, but it leads me to the right direction for now, so I honorably accepted the answer. Will report back with new findings after some tests are completed...

Comment: please do. I take personal intrest in knowing the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So formulating this as an answer. Take a look at the yahoo tips for speeding up your website. 
[yahoo developer network](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

mainly take care of caching, cache-control and expiry date headers. This has mainly direct influence on the content not the headers but you never know.

Take a look at this [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480773/how-to-speed-up-web-development-with-correct-apache-caching-headers-setup)

Again its about caching
You should also use gzip or module defalt, but again this influences the contents only

Answer (score 1):

Is 11kb of headers normal? Unfortunately, it's not unusual. Is 11kb a lot - definitely. Think of it this way: that's 11kb of data your browser has to download *before* any of the page data can come through on the wire. If you want to make your site faster, then reducing the amount of time and data that has to be delivered before the first (useful) bytes of the page is a good optimization.

1) Check what's actually consuming all that header space. Chances are, you may have cookies and other data that can be reduced in size.

Having said that, the problem here is not headers exclusively. Instead, based on your diagram it takes your server ~100ms to start serving the headers. It looks like you have redirect, and then another 50ms to generate the response.

2) Can you eliminate the redirect?
3) All things considered, 50ms to generate the response **is not** unreasonable. If you are capturing above test on local server, then maybe you can reduce the server time through optimization. But for remote cases, 50ms is actually pretty fast - speed of light, not much we can do about it. :-)

P.S. Here's some more info on latency: http://www.igvita.com/2012/07/19/latency-the-new-web-performance-bottleneck/